# Copy a file to several directories with gulp

Tags: copy, gulp

I would like to copy a specific file `style.css` to several directories css folder by the use of gulp, for exmple:

```
Project
- directory 1
 - css
- directory 2
 - css
- directory 3
 - css
- directory 4
 - css
- style.css
```

---

As far as I understood, gulp can only copy **a file or several files** into **one directory** not several directories.

```
gulp.task('copy', function() {
  return gulp.src('project/style.css')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('project'));
});
```

Consider that I know it is possible to write several `gulp.dest` but I need a dynamic way to handle many directory.
So is there any solution out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a *single* source onto which you add calls to `.pipe(gulp.dest(...))` and then return that result:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");

gulp.task('default', function () {
    var dests = ['./out1', './out2', './out3'];
    var stream = gulp.src('./project/style.css');
    for (var i = 0; i < dests.length; i++) {
        stream = stream.pipe(gulp.dest(dests[i]));
    }
    return stream;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here my suggestion for you. You can try something like that:

```
gulp.task('copy-multiple-dest', function () {

    return gulp.src('./project/style.css')

    .pipe(gulp.dest('./directory 1'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./directory 2'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./directory 3'));

});
```

UPDATE:  (Not sure if this is good practice)

```
gulp.task('multiples', function () {  
    var directories = ['./directory 1', './directory 2'];  
    for (var i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {  
        gulp.src('./project/style.css')  
            .pipe(gulp.dest(directories[i]));  
    }
});
```

Comment: I know this, but I need a dynamic way, because in my real project there are over 50 directores not only 3.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure it's the best way, but you could read your directories through node's fs, and optionally filter them with a regex, then use pipe each of the resulting name as a destination through a reduce

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readdirSync('project').filter(function(fname) {
    return fname.match(/directory\s\d+/);
}).reduce(function(stream, dest){
    return stream.pipe(gulp.dest('project/'+dest+'/css'));
}, gulp.src('project/style.css'));
```